# Glossaries Array Vertical Formatting Problem

Tags: glossaries

Using some examples from this site as well as the glossaries doc I was able to get some custom glossary styles working for my thesis report. However, I noticed a very strange formatting issue in the array table I use:

[image: Random vertical spacing in table]

This gets solved whenever I put the glossary entry name field in math mode (e.g. $ABC$ instead of ABC in the mwe below). But this dirty trick is not a nice way of displaying my acronyms in non-italic bold font as I desire. It ends up like this:

[image: Quick'n ugly fix using math mode in 'name' label]

I have spent hours upon hours trying to figure this out, considering virtually every line in the code, including alternate ways of indexing and compiling and using multiple loadglsentries (not included in mwe below). Can someone explain to me what is going on here? Much appreciate your help.

Compile this mwe with

```
pdflatex %.tex|makeindex -s %.ist -t %.alg -o %.acr %.acn|pdflatex %.tex.
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{tabx3col}{%
 % put the glossary in a longtable environment:
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
  {\begin{longtable}{p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.7\textwidth}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
 % Set the table's header:
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
 % No heading between groups:
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
 % Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row:
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glstarget{##1}{\textbf{##2}}% Name
    & \glsentryuseri{##1}   
    & ##3 % Description
    \\ % end of row
  }%
}

\newglossary[alg]{acronym}{acr}{acn}{Nomenclature}

%% glossary entries
%\loadglsentries[acronym]{acronyms.tex}

\newglossaryentry{abc}{name={ABC},description={First three letters      alphabet},type={acronym}}
\newglossaryentry{123}{name={123},description={First three numbers},type={acronym}}
\newglossaryentry{TEX}{name={TEX},description={Latex scripting language},type={acronym}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type={acronym},style={tabx3col}]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there's a vertical gap between each letter group. This is determined by the conditional `\ifglsnogroupskip` which can be set using the package `nogroupskip` package option. The command `\glsgroupskip` usually queries this conditional to determine whether or not to add the vertical gap. Your style doesn't override the default definition of `\glsgroupskip` which is defined as:

```
\ifglsnogroupskip \else \indexspace \fi
```

This means that your style is trying to insert `\indexspace` between letter groups which conflicts with the `longtable` environment. To fix this you just need to add

```
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
```

to your style.

You're also using a deprecated command in your style. The newer usage should redefine `\glossentry` rather than `\glossaryentryfield`:

```
\newglossarystyle{tabx3col}{%
 % put the glossary in a longtable environment:
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
  {\begin{longtable}{p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.7\textwidth}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
 % Set the table's header:
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
 % No heading between groups:
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
 % Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row:
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glstarget{##1}{\textbf{\glossentryname{##1}}}% Name
    & \glsentryuseri{##1}   
    & \glossentrydesc{##1} % Description
    \\ % end of row
  }%
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You've made my day. And thank you for all the hard work put in the glossaries package. :)